# Android - getting current playing media/url from adb

Tags: media-player

How can we go about getting the current playing media (in this case hulu).  We would like to know the URL or the asset id via adb if possible.

Comment: You first need to find out which activity of the Hulu app accepts URLs. The you could construct a command-line using `am start` the activity name, the command `-a android.intent.action.VIEW` and the URL as `-d` argument. A bit similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/58458736/150978 just additionally with the activity to be started.

Comment: Thanks we have the playing part working.  What we want to do is check which media is playing via ADB (or some other method?) via our scripts.

Comment: `am start` does not return anything so this way will not work. Does Hulu show a media notificvation (where you can pause/play the currently active media)? If it shows such a notification then you should try to read the notification.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not seeing a media notification when pausing as it's live TV in this case.